# How to publish a COM-Visible library created with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com

I have to create a COM library from a C# project, but I'm pretty stuck with referencing the external libraries.

I have set "Make assembly COM-Visible" in the project's properties and when I build it creates the dll and it puts all required dll's in the bin/Release directory.

## Libraries used

All libraries are .NET imported with NuGet or System libraries.

[image]

## Creating the .tlb file

When I run a command to create a .tlb file, it is created, but it also shows a warning:

```
tlbexp.exe "MyLib.dll"

TlbExp : warning TX00131175 : When cross-compiling, all type library references should be included on the command line to ensure the correct bit-specific type libraries are loaded.
Assembly exported to 'C:\Workspace\MyProject\bin\MyLib.tlb'
```

It looks like this library is ready to be shipped, but I'm wondering if I can just ignore the warning.

And, what is the best way to ship this COM-Visible library?
Can I just ship the entire *bin/Release* directory, or should I use another method?

Comment: Not enough information. Need to know what other kind of type libraries (.NET or unmanaged COM?) you are using from your library. Normally you would not distribute the .tlb files unless you are using isolated COM. Instead, you would register the assembly on the target machine so that the registry entries would be correctly entered. You might distribute the .tlb files if you are manually setting the registry entries for your .NET COM server.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I updated my question and added the libraries, which are all plain .NET. Am I correct to conclude I can just ship the library with all it's dependencies without the .tlb, let the user save the entire directory somewhere on their machine and use regasm.exe to register to COM server?

Comment: Very important to test this, preferably with the same kind of programming tool that the client uses.  Only way to find out that the answer is "no".  Many existing questions about it.

Comment: More or less true. You need to register for the correct architecture (x86 vs x64, i.e. 32-bit vs 64-bit, i.e. Framework vs Framework64) and right platform (2.0 vs 4.0--but probably assume 4.0+ at this point). If you build with standard .NET project settings, it compiles to architecture independent MSIL and you can register the server with x86 and/or x64. However, the caller that instantiates must be of the same architecture. A simple test to try and instantiate your object is to use VBS with a script like "set obj = CreateObject("Your.ProgID")" using cscript.exe in system32 and syswow64.

Answer (score 0):

Well the .tlb is needed just to reference your library from a development tool ( for example Visual C++ ), referencing correctly does not mean that program, after compiling correctly, will work. This because you need to proper install the dll on the target machine, typically you need to `xcopy` the dll with all dependencies, and then use `regasm.exe` ( specifying the `/CODEBASE` flag I suggest, so you can point surely the dll you want on your file system ). Of course even proper Framework has to be installed too.